# Dreamweaver spry widgets compatibility

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, compatibility, spry

Just wondering if Dreamweaver widgets (e.g. TabbedPanels, menu bars, etc.) are compatible with most browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they should be compatible with all of the recent versions of major browsers.  IE6 can give some of the Spry widgets problems though.